# WhatsAPI Interfaces and service abuse

Tags: whatsapp

if i want to use Whatspp API to send official advertising or greeting. 
is it consider abuse of the service?
is there any official way to interface with WhatsApp?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is abuse of the service to spam people.

And the official way to interface with whatsapp, is to install it on your phone and send messages to your pals. Unofficial APIs to interface with it are available however, but spammers are not supported by the API maintainers.

Comment: Thanks. is there anyway to register the sender as not a spammer?

Comment: Nope, just don't send spam, and you won't have a problem.